# Ruby local Gem acting in Docker container

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, local

As the last resource before I throw all this refactoring away I am asking this question here. There is this strange behaviour I am facing. I am new to Ruby so most likely it is something I am doing wrong.

I extracted some common functionality into a local Gem which works when running the Sinatra App locally (It is a simple Github App).

But when I try running into a Docker container, it would seem to only run the calls to the Gem after I shutdown (Ctrl+c) the application (Logs appear after Sinatra finishes).

[image: Ruby Logs Docker Image]

To Build the image I am doing the steps below:

```
FROM ruby:slim-buster

ARG GITHUB_APP_IDENTIFIER
ARG GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET
ARG GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY
ARG ACCESS_TOKEN

RUN apt update && apt install -y git --no-install-recommends

COPY LineEnding/line_ending.rb LineEnding/Gemfile LineEnding/Gemfile.lock /line_ending/
COPY github_gem/ /github_gem
WORKDIR /github_gem
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install
RUN gem install github_gem-0.1.0.gem
WORKDIR /line_ending
RUN bundle install

ENV GITHUB_APP_IDENTIFIER ${GITHUB_APP_IDENTIFIER}
ENV GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET ${GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET}
ENV GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY ${GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY}
ENV ACCESS_TOKEN ${ACCESS_TOKEN}

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["ruby", "line_ending.rb"]
```

When running locally, works perfectly, and the logs are like:

[image]

As another piece of information, I tried piping the logs in Docker like:

```
def initialize
  docker_stdout = IO.new(IO.sysopen("/proc/1/fd/1", "w"),"w")

  @logger = Logger.new(docker_stdout)
  @logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
end
```

It didn't make any difference, both STDOUT and docker_stdout behave in the same manner.

Complete error log:

```
[2020-11-17 10:20:48] INFO  WEBrick 1.6.0
[2020-11-17 10:20:48] INFO  ruby 2.7.2 (2020-10-01) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra (v2.0.4) has taken the stage on 3001 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2020-11-17 10:20:48] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=3001
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.306766 #1] DEBUG -- : request
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.308179 #1] DEBUG -- : Authenticate app
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.308209 #1] DEBUG -- : 2020-11-17 10:21:00.308206249 +0000
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.308245 #1] DEBUG -- : 1605608460
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.308290 #1] DEBUG -- : 1605609060
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.312411 #1] DEBUG -- : Get installation key
WARNING: The preview version of the Integrations API is not yet suitable for production use.
You can avoid this message by supplying an appropriate media type in the 'Accept' request
header.
2020-11-17 10:21:08 - Faraday::ConnectionFailed - Failed to open TCP connection to github.com:443 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution):
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `initialize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `open'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `block in connect'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/timeout.rb:95:in `block in timeout'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/timeout.rb:105:in `timeout'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:958:in `connect'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:943:in `do_start'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:932:in `start'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:152:in `request_via_request_method'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:137:in `request_with_wrapped_block'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:128:in `perform_request'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:70:in `block in call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/adapter.rb:61:in `connection'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:68:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/response.rb:11:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/response.rb:11:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/octokit-4.19.0/lib/octokit/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:73:in `perform_with_redirection'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/octokit-4.19.0/lib/octokit/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:61:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/request/retry.rb:148:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:154:in `build_response'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:492:in `run_request'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.1.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:279:in `post'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sawyer-0.8.2/lib/sawyer/agent.rb:94:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/octokit-4.19.0/lib/octokit/connection.rb:156:in `request'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/octokit-4.19.0/lib/octokit/connection.rb:28:in `post'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/octokit-4.19.0/lib/octokit/client/apps.rb:78:in `create_app_installation_access_token'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/github_gem-0.1.0/lib/github_gem.rb:137:in `authenticate_installation'
    line_ending.rb:69:in `block in <class:GHAapp>'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1635:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1635:in `block in compile!'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1040:in `block in process_route'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1038:in `catch'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1038:in `process_route'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:983:in `block in filter!'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:983:in `each'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:983:in `filter!'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1096:in `block in dispatch!'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1076:in `block in invoke'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1076:in `catch'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1076:in `invoke'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1094:in `dispatch!'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:924:in `block in call!'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1076:in `block in invoke'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1076:in `catch'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1076:in `invoke'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:924:in `call!'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:913:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-2.0.4/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-2.0.4/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-2.0.4/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:26:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-2.0.4/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:50:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-2.0.4/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:50:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-2.0.4/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/common_logger.rb:33:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:231:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:224:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:194:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1957:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1502:in `block in call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1729:in `synchronize'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1502:in `call'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/webrick/server.rb:307:in `block in start_thread'
16.85.88.12 - - [17/Nov/2020:10:20:59 UTC] "POST /event_handler HTTP/1.1" 500 190501
- -> /event_handler
^C== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
[2020-11-17 10:21:10] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2020-11-17 10:21:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
[2020-11-17 10:21:10] INFO  WEBrick 1.6.0
[2020-11-17 10:21:10] INFO  ruby 2.7.2 (2020-10-01) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra (v2.0.4) has taken the stage on 3001 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2020-11-17 10:21:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=3001
^C== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
[2020-11-17 10:21:10] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2020-11-17 10:21:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.306932 #1] DEBUG -- : ---- get payload
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.307577 #1] DEBUG -- : ---- verify webhook signature
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.308133 #1] DEBUG -- : ---- received event check_run
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.308160 #1] DEBUG -- : ----    action created
D, [2020-11-17T10:21:00.312187 #1] DEBUG -- : ---- authenticate Client
```

Comment: Your first Screenshot has an error-backtrace inside (first lines), which is not fully shown. Can you attach the backtrace as text or as an image?

Comment: As text, please.  Do not attach screenshots of terminal windows to your questions.  It'd be better if you could replace the images above with the plain-text output of the process.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that.

Comment: As an update, I continued testing and the app worked after all. There was also a network issue involved. BUT the logging is still in weird order. The logs from the gem are coming back only when Sinatra takes back control. Do I need to pass a logger to the gem? sounds weird.